# show cartthrob packages product in front end

Tags: cartthrob, sessions

I want to show cartthrob packages in front-end after login when i login i am not able to see product which are used to add in packages shown in below image

Its work when we have logged in from back-end

When i try to debug i found i am not getting EE.base so i have add below think to use for dynamic user

"http://stores.example.com/system/index.php?S=$fingerprint&D=cp";

?S=$fingerprint is same as below which i am getting when i am logged in back-end

In backend the url is some think link this http://stores.example.com/system/index.php?S=d880f2cb5dd6db612d0603c2b95272e3&D=cp&XID=ba318af777c8317b9a5e4ee803f72ea8dbbc223a&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=cartthrob&method=package_filter&filter_id=1&keywords=&channel_id=null&date_range=&cat_id=&search_in=title

I have tried to debug once again 
print_r($this->EE->session->userdata);

i found all the values same except  [admin_sess] it will be 1 when i login from backend and 0 else

so please help me how to show cartthrob packages product in front end

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i call to support they  said  packages feature was never meant to show on the front end.

The problem was in **"EE.BASE"**  on line no 166 => $.getJSON(EE.BASE, filter, function(data) and need to set **"admin_sess"**

When the front-end user login we need to set admin_sess to 1
and need to set EE.BASE

You can set EE.BASE as $this->EE->session->userdata['fingerprint']; or user session
Need to add update query to set admin session to 1